# Promisify read csv files into json with Bluebird function

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I am a beginner using the promise bluebird in node js to read all the csv files and convert to json in a bluebird function, but for some reason I can't get it right.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

var Converter = Promise.promisifyAll(require("csvtojson")).Converter;


Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);
var conversionJsons = Promise.promisifyAll(jsons);

function jsons (data){
  return {
    then: function(callback){
      var converter = new Converter({});
      converter.fromStringAsync(data).then(function(result){
        console.log("results are: "+ JSON.stringify(result));  
        callback(result);
      });
    }
  };
};


fs.readdirAsync(dir).map(function(fileName) {

  var contents = fs.readFileAsync(fileName).catch(function ignore() {});
    return join(fileName, contents, function(fileName, contents) {
        return {
          fileName: fileName,
          contents: contents
        }
    });


}).each(function(file) {

    conversionJsons(file.contents.toString()).then(function(result){
      console.log("Size: "+ result.length);
    });

}).then(function(contents) {
    console.log('Done.............');
})
```

**my steps are:**

1. Read all the csv files using the fs module.
2. convert the content of the csv into json.
3. report 'done....' when all the files are read.

**this is my output.**

*Done.............*

*results are: [{"Order_id":1,"Quantity":70,"Price":100},{"Order_id":2,"Quantity":
50,"Price":100},{"Order_id":3,"Quantity":101,"Price":10}]*

*results are: 3*

console.log('Done.............') is called before step 1 and 2.

**Edited:**

this is my latest update. I made the function jsons a promise function.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

var Converter = Promise.promisifyAll(require("csvtojson")).Converter;


Promise.promisifyAll(Converter.prototype);
var conversionJsons = Promise.promisifyAll(jsons);

function jsons (data){
  return {
    then: function(callback){
    var convertion = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var converter = new Converter({});
    var output="";
    converter.fromStringAsync(data).then(function(result){
      console.log('processing');
      return result;
    });

      });
    }
  };
};

fs.readdirAsync(dir).map(function(fileName) {

  var contents = fs.readFileAsync(fileName).catch(function ignore() {});
    return join(fileName, contents, function(fileName, contents) {
        return {
          fileName: fileName,
          contents: contents
        }
    });

}).each(function(file) {
  console.log("results are: "+ file.contents);
  return conversionJsons(file.contents.toString()).then(function(result){
    console.log("Size: "+ result.length);
  });
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log("Final results are: "+ JSON.stringify(result)); 
  console.log('Done.............');
})
```

**MY OUTPUT**

results are: Order_id,Quantity,Price
1,70,100
2,50,100
3,101,10

Final results are: [{"fileName":"pizza.csv","contents":{"type":"Buffer","data":[
79,114,100,101,114,95,105,100,44,81,117,97,110,116,105,116,121,44,80,114,105,99,
101,13,10,49,44,55,48,44,49,48,48,13,10,50,44,53,48,44,49,48,48,13,10,51,44,49,4
8,49,44,49,48,13,10]}}]

Done.............

processing

Comment: You forgot to `return` from the `each` callback

Comment: I put in return result just like to suggest:

   conversionJsons(file.contents.toString()).then(function(result){
      console.log("Size: "+ result.length);
      return result;
    });


I am doing it wrong since it still gives me the same output.

Comment: Ah right there as well, but I meant the `each` callback not the `then` callback which is important for the execution order.

Comment: I am new with this, so I apologize, but I don't really understand where the return should be. I tried to put the return outside the conversionJsons, but still same output.

}).each(function(file) {
    var readData=[];
    conversionJsons(file.contents.toString()).then(function(result){
      console.log("Size: "+ result.length);
      readData = result;
    });
    return readData;

Comment: Where did you get that `readData` from now? Just `return conversionJsons(file.contents.toString()).then(…);`. Remember: If the (callback) function does something asynchronous, it must return a promise for the result.

Comment: I already tried that one, but that yield the same output result. I think it has to do with the conversionJsons function that is not a promise for some reason while I promisified it, but I am not sure.

Comment: I put my latest update here above. No error. For some reason, the data past to the then function is strange. It doesn't contain the JSON data array generated from the conversionjsons function. The order is still off. 'Done....' comes before the promisify function conversionJsons